# Printing in loop

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have following code to print to the System-Default printer:

```py
def printFile(file):
    print("printing file...")
    with open(file, "rb") as source:
        printer = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/lpr', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        printer.stdin.write(source.read())
```

This function works quite well if I use it on its own. But if use it in a loop construct like this:

```py
while True:
     printFile(file)
     (...)
```

the printing job won't run (although) the loop will continue without error...

I tried to build in a time delay, but it didn't helped...

[Edit]: further investigations showed me that the printing function (when called from the loop) will put the printing jobs on hold...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Python3, it is advised to use `subprocess.run()` in most cases instead of using `subprocess.Popen` directly. And I would leave it to `lpr` to read the file, rather than passing it to standard input:

```
def printFile(file):
    print("printing file...")
    cp = subprocess.run(['\usr\bin\lpr', file])
    return cp.returncode
```

Using `subprocess.run` allows you to ascertain that the `lpr` process finished correctly. And this way you don't have to read and write the complete file. You can even remove the file once `lpr` is finished.

Using `Popen` directly has some disadvantages here;

1. Using `Popen.stdin` might produce a deadlock if it overfills the OS pipe buffers (according to the Python docs).
2. Since you don't `wait()` for the `Popen` process to finish, you don't know if it finished without errors.

Depending on how `lpr` is set up, it might have rate controls. That is, it might stop printing if it gets a lot of print requests in a short span of time.

**Edit**: I just thought of something. Most `lpr` implementations allow you to print more than one file at a time. So you could also do:

```
def printFile(files):
    """
    Print file(s).

    Arguments:
        files: string or sequence of strings.
    """
    if isinstance(files, str):
        files = [files]
    # if you want to be super strict...
    if not isinstance(files (list, tuple)):
        raise ValueError('files must be a sequence type')
    else:
        if not all(isinstance(f, str) for f in files):
            raise ValueError('files must be a sequence of strings')
    cp = subprocess.run(['\usr\bin\lpr'] + files)
    return cp.returncode
```

That would print a single file or a whole bunch of them in one go...